# Is there a way in Jenkins to create a symlink a job which runs in another Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Consider the following situation. There is a Jenkins (JenkinsNr1) with a job called "Dummy". I want to mirror this job to another Jenkins (JenkinsNr2). The job should only run in JenkinsNr1 but I have to be able to configure it and see the results in JenkinsNr2 too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this, it will be bad practice.

Each server has its own set of jobs to manage, and this is how it should be.

Because Jenkins is available on the web,
you should concentrate on making it available to those who need to manage the different jobs,
instead of trying to duplicate those jobs.

(also you should consider having one instance run as a slave of the other,
instead of having two servers)

Cheers